# Hudson not building the Project

Tags: ios, svn, hudson

I am using Hudson with subversion for build automation.

I have configured a job to build, but Hudson is not building the project - it's just giving the following log message. I have no clue what's going on.

```
Started by user admin
Updating someaddress/iOS/Apps/iPhoneApp/_Iphone revision: Nov 16, 2012 3:56:11 PM depth:infinity ignoreExternals: true
At revision 119
no revision recorded for someaddress/iOS/Apps/iPhoneApp/_Iphone in the previous build
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update; build not configured with trigger: MyFirstBuildJob #44
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: How have you configured Hudson to do the actual building?

Comment: i followed thos link: http://acornheroes.com/2010/08/setting-up-an-automated-build-in-an-ios-environment-part-2/

Comment: Do you have the same build steps as in that link? Even if there has been no change in the repo, it should still attempt to build something when the job is manually started.

Comment: Can you paste the content of your "execute shell" build step(s)?